# AnguluarJS prevent caching of one specific template load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, caching

I have a situation where an external link is opening my app, the info in the link then autoloads a content from my server into a specific template/page.

All my app template pages are cached, but the caching of this specific page, when loading content directed from the external link, is causing weird issues.  When I turn caching off the problems go away.

Is it possible to have caching on for that specific page, but when loading content from the external link to turn caching off just that one time - then turn caching back on for any subsequent page loads?

```
.state('tab.search', {
   cache: true,
   url: '/search',
   params: {caching: null},
   views: {
      'tab-search': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search.html',
         controller: 'SearchCtrl'
       }
})
```

Is there something that I can put in the controller:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function() {
   $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
      if ($stateParams.caching == false) {
         $state['tab.search'].cache = false ;   <==== something like this?
   }) ;
}) ;
```

And then turn it on again later:
$state['tab.search'].cache = true ;

Comment: Define "causing weird issues" in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl - lol.  Well, when the primary page loads it has an `ng-init="$last && listLoaded()"` in the `ng-repeat`, listLoaded then checks if the page/productID request originated from an external link, if so, then route to that product page details.  All works.  But clicking back to the original list some list elements `ng-click="openProduct()" (which hides/unhides sub-list info) aren't applying the appropriate styles to hide/show the sub-list.  I can see the ng-click functions being initiated, but styles aren't being applied.  If not an external link request, then everything works fine.